# Expression ("Product") of matrices that implies one of the factors is zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

The complex numbers have these two properties:

$\begin{align}
\sum_i a_i \bar{a_i}&=0 \implies \mkern-2em&\text{all}\ a_i&=0 \tag{and} \\
\prod_i a_i &=0 \implies \mkern-2em &\text{at least one}\ a_i&=0 \tag{or}
\end{align}$

The **(and)** property also exists for matrices:

$\begin{align}
\sum_i A_i {A_i^{\dagger}}&=0 \implies \qquad &\text{all}\ A_i&=0 \tag{and}\\
\end{align}$

But what about the **(or)** property? The naive generalization doesn't work, since matrices have zero divisors. But maybe there is a different generalization.

Preferably this property reduces to the $1$-dim case (as in the case of the **(and)** property), and so somehow involves products of the $i$ matrices (but it doesn't have to).

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best generalization we can get is that
$\prod A_i$ is singular (non-invertible) if and only if one of the $A_i$ are singular. If we use determinants to show this, then this is really a direct application of the result on $\Bbb C$.